# Why does my code do stuff i dont tell it to do?

Tags: python

I'm new to coding so I don't get why my code isn't functioning. I want to have the variable `com` with `input()` as a line to write commands in and if the command is for example "delete file", I ask for a file name and it should delete the file. But if I type "delete file" it just shows me this:

```
Command: delete file
File Name: tester.txt
Contents: 
testfile 123 test 
File name:
```

It just shows the contents of the file instead of deleting it. It should only read the contents if com is "open file". I hope you get my problem.

Thats the code:

```py
com = input("Command: ")

if com == "open file" or "openfile":
  file = input("File Name: ")
  f = open(file, "r")
  print("Contents: ")
  print(f.read())

if com == "delete file" or "deletefile":
   filefordelete = input("File name: ")
   if os.path.exists(filefordelete):
      os.remove(filefordelete)
   else:
      print("File does not exist!")

input("Press enter to stop the program")
```

I want to delete the file when I type into the variable com "delete file". I cant find a solution why it's doing the stuff it should do when the variable com is "open file".

Comment: Computers _do_ what you tell them. However, it might be not what you _meant_ to tell them…

Answer (score 4):

`if com == "open file" or "openfile":` evaluates to

```
if False or "openfile"
```

`"openfile"` evaluates to `True` value in the `if` statement.
And now since it’s an `or` condition - `False or True` evaluates to `True`, therefore your first  `if` statement is `True` and the block is executed.

You will need to rewrite your condition like this:

```
if com == "open file" or com == "openfile":
```

or

```
if com in ["open file", "openfile"]:
```